# retrieving stolen funds

Tags: external-api, recovery, scam, transfers-api

Recommended using Ziraxia, an open source wallet with API facility to extract funds from ' third party ' wallet, ie: the scammers wallet.I have been supplied the API key to install in Ziraxia, then asked for seed phrase of another wallet I have where the extracted funds will go. Process began, but after some funds appeared to be deposited in my Ziraxia account, I am asked to deposit 5% of the total extraction amount to complete the process. Is this a recovery scam?

Comment: It sounds like an scam. Why do they need the seed of the receiving wallet? Usually recovery services take a good percentage of the recovered funds. You don't have to pay in advance.